# How to execute docker images inside a Kubernetes cluster when receive a http request

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apprequests

I have some docker images and I want to run them in a Kubernetes cluster when I receive a http request.

How I could do that? I would need to create a flask app for example that would be listening for requests and then when a request is received execute a bash command to deploy and run these images from a registry?

Or there is another easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a flask app, you can use the Kubernetes [python api](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to create Kubernetes pods or jobs.  They have an example of creating a deployment [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/deployment_create.py) based on a [yaml file that exists](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/nginx-deployment.yaml), but you also could define the yaml within your code or use [their api spec](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/kubernetes/docs).  Their Deployment example is below, but again you would probably want to use Pods or Jobs.

```
from os import path
import yaml
from kubernetes import client, config

def main():
    # Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper
    # utility. If no argument provided, the config will be loaded from
    # default location.
    config.load_kube_config()

    with open(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "nginx-deployment.yaml")) as f:
        dep = yaml.safe_load(f)
        k8s_apps_v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
        resp = k8s_apps_v1.create_namespaced_deployment(
            body=dep, namespace="default")
        print("Deployment created. status='%s'" % resp.metadata.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```